# Android smoothScrollToPosition up top

Tags: android, listview, smooth-scrolling

I have set up `smoothScrollToPosition` on a `listview` and it works perfect! However... I would rather it put the position at the top of the `listview` rather than just on the screen (**mostly on the bottom if its needed to scroll down**). Any ideas how i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`smoothScrollToPositionFromTop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop%28int,%20int,%20int%29). It places the item at the specified position a specified number of pixels from the top of the ListView (if possible). You should simply supply a small offset.

Note: requires API level 11+.

Answer (score 0):

```
 recycleviewlist.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CountDownTimer(totalScrollTime, scrollPeriod) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {      
                        recycleviewlist.smoothScrollBy( widthToScroll,0);                        
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        // gridlayoutmanager
                        // recycleviewlist.scrollToPosition(0);
                        gridlayoutmanager1
                                .scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.